# object not found - writing subsetting function in R

Tags: r, list, function, nested-lists

I have this datasset :

```
dput(head(test1, 10))

structure(list(startdate = structure(c(1572994800, 1572994800, 
1572994800, 1572994800, 1572994800, 1572994800, 1572994800, 1572994800, 
1572994800, 1572994800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    id = c("POL55", "POL56", "POL57", "POL58", "POL59", "POL60", 
    "POL61", "POL62", "POL63", "POL64"), m0_9 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), m10_19 = c(NA, NA, NA, 32, 34, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 55), m20_29 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), m30_39 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 32), m40_49 = c(32, 
    34, NA, NA, NA, NA, 55, 3, NA, NA), m50_59 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 32, 34, NA, NA), m60_69 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), m70 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 32, 
    34, NA, NA), f0_9 = c(32, 34, NA, NA, NA, NA, 55, 3, NA, 
    NA), f10_19 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), f20_29 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), f30_39 = c(NA, NA, NA, 32, 
    34, NA, NA, NA, NA, 55), f40_49 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 32, 
    34, NA, NA, NA), f50_59 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), f60_69 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), f70 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 32)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I am writing a little function (which will be a part of a much larger function). However, i seem to be something wrong, as

```
test1$startdate <- as.POSIXct(test1$startdate, origin="1970-01-01")  

createLists("POL55", as.POSIXct(2019-11-27, origin="1970-01-01"))

createLists <- function(id, start){
  testFiltered = test1[id == id & startdate == start]

  ageGroup <- vector("list", length == nrow(testFiltered))
  names(ageGroup) <- as.character(seq_along(ageGroup))

  return(ageGroup)
}
```

how can i fix the error `object 'startdate' not found` ??

Comment: Were you expecting `test1` to be a `data.table`? Because that doesn't look like the right way to subset a `data.frame`. It would be something more like `testFiltered <- test1[test1$id == id & test1$startdate == start, ]` or with `testFiltered <- subset(test1, id == id & startdate == start)`

Comment: Are you aware that `2019-11-27` is a sequence of subtractions, not a character string? Correct what @MrFlick pointed out and then there is still `length == nrow(etc)`. **Only one `=`**, please...

Comment: when would it be possible to subset in this way? df_filterd = df[x == value & y == amount] ? lists maybe?... i am working on someone elses code, not sure why it is that way

Comment: @Danka I think that works with `data.table`s only. You would need that package and use those objects specifically.

Answer (score 0):

This should hopefully do the job.

```
createLists <- function(id, start) {
  testFiltered = test1[test1$id==id & test1$startdate == start,] # need test1$id etc.

  if(nrow(testFiltered) > 0) { # in case empty subset
     ageGroup <- vector("list", length = nrow(testFiltered))  # Only one '=' here
     names(ageGroup) <- as.character(seq_along(ageGroup))
     return(ageGroup)
  }
  else
     cat("Nothing to return\n")
}

createLists("POL55", as.POSIXct('2019-11-06', origin="1970-01-01"))
```

Hope it works for you. ☺