# subsetting data in R using single[ ] and no comma

Tags: r, list, function, subset

related to a previous question of [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60621477/object-not-found-writing-subsetting-function-in-r/60621891#60621891) about writing fuctions, i was wondering about subsetting in R. In which case would something like this be used? is it possible that `data_filtered` is stored in a list ?

```
data_filtered = data_full[id == FP438274 & start == 2019-19-9]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data frames *are* lists.

```
> class(iris)
[1] "data.frame"
> is.list(iris)
[1] TRUE
> is.data.frame(iris)
[1] TRUE
```

Data frames are a special type of list, with additional constraints (like, each list item, or *column*, must have the same length.)

If you use `[` with one comma then you subset the data frame as if it is a just a list---that is, you are subsetting the columns and ignoring the rows. `data[x]` is equivalent to `data[, x]`.

Assuming `id` and `start` are vectors of the same length as the *number of columns* in your data frame, then `data[id == FP438274 & start == 2019-19-9]` should work okay. If, as in your last question `id` and `start` have the same length as *the number of rows* in your data frame, then `data[id == FP438274 & start == 2019-19-9]` is nonsense.

(Also note that you almost certainly want `"2019-19-9"` or `as.Date("2019-19-9")`, as written `2019-19-9 = 2000 - 9 = 1991`, but I don't think subtraction is what you want.)

Comment: I'm guessing `data` is meant to be a `data.table`. It allows you to subset using column values in the that way.

Comment: That's a really good call--maybe worth commenting on [OP's original](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60621477/903061). They `dput` a tibble, but a data table makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I think not or that would be **selecting** (on variables - columns) as opposed to **subsetting** (on individuals - rows). For exemple using first 6 rows of the `mtcars` dataset you could transform the dataset to a list and do a selection based on the variables index :

```r
# dataset format
li1 <- head(mtcars)
rownames(li1) <- NULL
str( li1[1:2] ) # ok
#> 'data.frame':    6 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ mpg: num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1
#>  $ cyl: num  6 6 4 6 8 6

# list format
li <- as.list(head(mtcars))
str( li[1:2] ) # ok
#> List of 2
#>  $ mpg: num [1:6] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1
#>  $ cyl: num [1:6] 6 6 4 6 8 6
```

Things get ugly when you try to mix subsetting and selecting :

```r
# dataset format
str( li1[ li$mpg < 21 ] ) # ?
#> 'data.frame':    6 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76
#>  $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
#>  $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1

# list format
str( li[ li$mpg < 21 ] )
#> List of 3
#>  $ drat: num [1:6] 3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76
#>  $ wt  : num [1:6] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
#>  $ carb: num [1:6] 4 4 1 1 2 1
```

I can't explain yet the result of `li[ li$mpg < 21 ]`, if someone sees and want to help here I would be glad.

EDIT **Motus** : I understood that it was not your code that you need to clean. I think it is better you try to understand what was intended to write proper / more robust R code using the usual `[` operator with **comma** if there are several dimensions or `dplyr::slice()`/`dplyr::filter` format.

Comment: On the result of `li[ li$mpg < 21 ]`,  R *recycles* vectors by repeating them when they need to be longer. For example `x = rnorm(100); x[c(TRUE, FALSE)]` will give you every other `x` value. `mtcars[c(TRUE, FALSE)]` will give you every other column. `mtcars[c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)]` will give you columns 2,3,4,5,7,8,... In your example, ook at `li$mpg`, then look at `li$mpg < 21`, it gives 6 TRUE/FALSE values, FFFFTT, which will be recycled over the 11 columns of length, giving the  5,6, and 11th columns.

Comment: All code will not work if you don't understand what it's for. You don't give definitions for "proper" or "robust", but as much as I like `dplyr`, `[` is fundamental to R, and I think it is not good to equate it with neither "proper" nor "robust".

Comment: You are right. By `proper` or `robust` code I meant clear non ambiguous code like not the `li[ li$mpg < 21 ]` form which recycles argument and don't raise an error when there is no sense in this operation (at least to me). I have edited the comma part since it was not clear : `[` is my first choice.